# Wordpress Category vs. Sub-category Conditional

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, categories

I'm trying to develop two different templates; one layout for a category listing, and a separate layout for subcategories.

I believe it'd require a conditional statement detecting if the current category is a category or subcategory.

I'm familiar with:

```
<?php if (is_category('Category A')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_category('Category B')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I need this to be more dynamic and handle any category or subcategory without hard coding the cat ID number.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_category()` ([WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category#Examples)) to get all information about a category. Using this, you could create a custom conditional function in your **functions.php** like this:

```
function is_subcategory ($catid) {

  $currentcat = get_category($catid);

  if ( $currentcat->parent ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Now you could use this function, to determine if a category has a parent category, and therefore is a subcategory.

Unfortunately I don't know the context of your posted code. You'll somehow need to get the category id. Do you use the loop the walk the categories or a custom sql-query?

If the answer is not helping, maybe you could add some surrounding code to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and assistance. I would like amend this function, and possibly check to see if the $currentcat has a subcategory... how would this work?

Comment: And as for context, or to clarify, I want to use a different layout for a subcategory listing, separate from a parent category.

Comment: For example:
    <?php if ( is_subcategory() ) : ?>
     // one set of code
    <?php else : ?>
     // different set of code
    <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Checking if a category has subcategories requires a custom SQL-Query and a totally different function. How about this approach: Treat every category as a parent category, except if it has a parentid. Then it's a subcategory That way you can have two different templates. Is it important to know if a category has no children?